# Using Regex return None while the pattern is effectively present in the string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I ma trying to lear Regex but when I ma following a tutorial the regex I wrote return None.

```
import re


pattern = 'lion'
string = 'Le lion est l\'animal national de l\'Inde'

mo = re.match(pattern, string)

print(mo)

#Print None
```

Why ? lion is present in my string

Comment: `re.match` requires that matches start at the beginning of the string. Use `re.search` instead.

Comment: You're missing a ```\``` before the second `d`

Comment: @Nick Thank you for your quick and helpful replies, I figured it out that's why I suppress the post.

Answer (score 1):

`match` requires that the string *starts with* the given pattern. I suspect you're looking for a function more like `findall`.

```py
import re

pattern = r'lion'
string = 'Le lion est l\'animal national de l\'Inde'

mo = re.findall(pattern, string)

print(mo)
```

#### Output

```
['lion']
```